# Allow a user to change his password on a chrooted environment

Tags: ssh, password, sftp, chroot, passwd

I'm trying to setup a chrooted ssh and sftp server under Ubuntu server 16.04.3 LTS. I followed this tutorial:
https://rp29blog.wordpress.com/2016/06/26/setting-up-chroot-sftp-and-ssh

I got it working. I can do ssh and sftp to the chrooted environment, but I can't change the password of a chrooted user. I tried this:
-bash-4.3$ passwd

but I got:
passwd: Cannot determine your user name.

By the way, I also included the "/usr/bin/passwd" command in the chrooted environment and copied the files: group, group-, gshadow, gshadow-, passwd, and passwd- to the chrooted environment.

I also realized that if I do an "ls -l" in the chrooted environment, the group names won't be displayed. I will see things like:
drwxr-xr-x 3 0 33 4096 Feb 15 12:26 home

But in the real environment this entry looks like:
drwxr-xr-x 3 root www-data 4096 Feb 15 13:26 home

If I do sftp, then I will see the user and group names instead of their ids.

What could be the problem? I really need that the user is at least able to change its own password.

Best regards
Josef

Here my /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
UsePAM yes

Match group chrooted
    ChrootDirectory /home/ssh_chroot
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    #Uncomment to allow only sftp to the chrooted jail, ssh access will be denied
    #ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Here my folder structure:

```
/home/ssh_chroot
├── bin
│   ├── bash
│   ├── cat
│   ├── chown
│   ├── cp
│   ├── date
│   ├── ls
│   ├── mkdir
│   ├── mv
│   ├── rm
│   ├── rmdir
│   ├── sh
│   └── touch
├── dev
│   ├── null
│   ├── random
│   ├── tty
│   └── zero
├── etc
│   ├── group
│   ├── group-
│   ├── gshadow
│   ├── gshadow-
│   ├── hosts
│   ├── ld.so.cache
│   ├── ld.so.conf
│   ├── nsswitch.conf
│   ├── passwd
│   └── passwd-
├── home
│   └── chusr
├── lib
│   ├── libc.so.6
│   ├── libdl.so.2
│   ├── libncurses.so.5
│   ├── libtinfo.so.5
│   └── x86_64-linux-gnu
│       ├── libacl.so.1
│       ├── libattr.so.1
│       ├── libaudit.so.1
│       ├── libcrypt.so.1
│       ├── libc.so.6
│       ├── libdl.so.2
│       ├── libexpat.so.1
│       ├── libm.so.6
│       ├── libpam_misc.so.0
│       ├── libpam.so.0
│       ├── libpcre.so.3
│       ├── libpthread.so.0
│       ├── libselinux.so.1
│       ├── libtinfo.so.5
│       ├── libutil.so.1
│       └── libz.so.1
├── lib64
│   └── ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
├── sbin
│   └── unix_chkpwd
├── usr
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── clear
│   │   ├── dircolors
│   │   ├── groups
│   │   ├── id
│   │   ├── passwd
│   │   ├── tree
│   │   └── vi
│   └── lib
│       └── x86_64-linux-gnu
│           ├── libgpm.so.2
│           └── libpython3.5m.so.1.0
└── var
    └── www
```

Comment: Hey hi, I had faced simmilar issue with RedHat System and I do have Ubuntu servers as well but do not have simmilar setup there, but the point is, this Redhat link help me enable addition pam logging which in turn help me to solve my issue. and I'm quite sure it's simillar for ubuntu as well. So you can give it a try [here][1] is the link


  [1]: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1314883

Answer (score 0):

My question is actually not yet solved, but I think I will desist from it. I just thaught that it is a bad idea to copy the files: group, group-, gshadow, gshadow-, passwd, and passwd-, and shadow to the new environment.

Instead of working with passwords, I guess I will try to solve this with authentication keys. So that the user can generate its own keys with some password, then I will load them to the server.

This approach is still not safe since the user will work ages with a key, but I guess I can invalidate them from time to time, ie: each 6 months.

For the interested: I didn't got the error: "**Cannot determine your user name.**" anymore. Instead of it, I got:

```
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

after having entered the current user's password. I figured out that some files weren't found on the chroot environment by doing this:

```
strace passwd
```

particularly I watched the paths on each stat(), read(), open(), connect(), access(), statfs(), and readlink() call. So, I copied some files or entired folders and linked/binded some devices. But I didn't got it working.

Anyway, I desisted of doing this for two reasons:

1. One of my objectives is to hide some parts of the system in the chroot. Howerver, if I had to copy lots of files from my main system, then what's the point of doing this?
2. I also think that duplicating the main password file my have some problems: you will have it on two different places: on your main system and on the chroot. So, if I get "passwd" to work, were will be the new password stored? I guess in the chroot copy, so, the next time the user logins, its password will be still the old one stored on the main passwd file, isn't it?

I'm just wondering how hosting companies solve this with their "shared hosting" programs. I have been customer of several of them and I can see that when I use the ssh access they offer, I only see a limited system; even the password file is not there. I think I only saw my home folder and some log files from my websites.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved the password problem with a public and a private key. The trick here is to put the public key in: /home/your_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

It must be in the real root an not in the home located inside the chroot; otherwise, the key authentication won't work.

Only one problem remains here and is that you can't force complex passphrases. If the user wants, he can put either an empty phrase or something like: "1234".

I really wish I could work with password authentication. You can at least force some password complexity with pam.